# How to get rid of MaxPermSize warning when trying to open Eclipse?

Tags: linux-mint, eclipse, openjdk

I'm brand-new to linux, using Mint. I installed Eclipse, but when I try to open it or do commands involving it I get an error. Earlier, this came up:

`OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0.`

I've been all over other forums because a lot of people have had this issue. Following their advice, I went into /etc and from there into the eclipse.ini file and commented out:

`--launcher.XXMaxPermSize`

`256m`

But it didn't fix it. My problem is that I'm really new and most of the advice on other forums just goes right over my head--I want to learn about everything but if anyone is using fancy (for my standards haha) vocab then please explain briefly what the words mean so I can follow! Also, if there are any specific commands or anything that I should enter, I would greatly appreciate some explanation of how that command works so I'm learning and not just plugging random stuff into my terminal until it works. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message you are seeing is just a warning. The `-XX:MaxPermSize` and `-XX:PermSize` options are ignored since JDK8, the PermGen space was completely removed and replaced by the new MetaSpace.

There might be an additional line `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m` at the end of your `eclipse.ini` which you forgot to remove, so you still get a warning message.

See this related post on stackoverflow:

- [PermGen elimination in JDK 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339707/permgen-elimination-in-jdk-8)

Comment: I'm now wondering if maybe I have a different problem than the PermSize thing. This post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412617/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-eclipse-core-runtime-adaptor-eclipsestarte is about the exact exception I'm getting when I try to open. Maybe helpful to others.